# File exist not working with a variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a Windows batch file I can get exist to work on a file name string but not on a file name variable.

```
@echo off

SetLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set Route_Riter=C:\Program Files (x86)\Route_Riter
echo.%Route_Riter%
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Route_Riter" (
 echo.Route_Riter is installed.
)
if not exist "!Router_Riter!" (
 echo.Route_Riter not installed.
 exit /b
)
```

The if with the text constant tests true while the test using the variable returns false. The batch output is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Route_Riter
Route_Riter is installed.
Route_Riter is not installed.
```

Using %Route_Riter% in the second if gives an error of

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I intend to set the variable by reading from a registry key but first want to get it working with the variable set to a constant string. The constant would also be used if the registry key is not present.

Comment: Delayed expansion only helps inside `for` and `do` blocks. Just use regular expansion, as in `"%router_riter%"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not exist "!Router_Riter!" (
```

should be

```
if not exist "!Route_Riter!" (
```

or preferably

```
if not exist "%Route_Riter%" (
```

`Router_Riter` is not defined, hence the "erroneous" bahaviour.

I could not reproduce your `syntax error` using `%`.

Comment: That was an embarrassing error. Is there a way to flag undefined variables or require that variables are defined?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Using them in a statement which yields a syntax error if they're not defined is a good way. You could also prefix each statemt with `if defined varname...` but then there's twice the chance of a typo and twice the code to write and maintain. I traced it by duplicating the line and converting to an `echo`; observing the empty variable and then recognising the typo. As a COBOL programmer, I'm in favour of descriptive names, but I draw the line when I have to use the shift key. Underscores make the names hard to read (as well as to type) in my view.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be very careful when detecting folders in DOS/Windows..  Best thing to keep in mind as it is not very obvious is that folder is really a "fancy" file in DOS/Windows.  You are still checking for the existence of a file, but you have to treat it differently.

I would use the following (NOTE: The trailing slash with dot is important):

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Route_Riter\." (
 echo.Route_Riter is installed.
)
```

In fact, I would use the following as you are probably dealing with a mix of 32-64 bit machines:

```
if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Route_Riter\." (
 echo.Route_Riter is installed.
)
```